# Terraform array to map(any)

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm using the community provided AWS API Gateway v2 module https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-apigateway-v2/ to provision a new API gateway for my infrastructure.

I'm provisioning a microservice architecture, so have multiple lambda functions that I need to route to.

In terraform, I currently haven an array that defines each of my microservices so I can provision each ECR, Lambda etc... using a `for_each` statement.

For my API Gateway, I want to generate the integrations block dynamically as well, using the array as a base.

My array is defined as:

```
locals {
   services = ["identity", "organisation"]
}
```

Then I'm trying to build my API Gateway:

```
module "api_gateway" {
  source = "../modules/apigateway"

  name          = "${var.name}-${var.env}-api-gateway"
  ...
 
  integrations = {
    "ANY /identity/{proxy+}" = {
      lambda_arn             = module.api_lambdas["identity"].lambda_function_arn
      payload_format_version = "1.0"
      timeout_milliseconds   = 12000
    }
    "ANY /organisation/{proxy+}" = {
      lambda_arn             = module.api_lambdas["organisation"].lambda_function_arn
      payload_format_version = "1.0"
      timeout_milliseconds   = 12000
    }
  } 
}
```

But instead of repeating the content of integrations for each of my services, I'd like to be able to dynamically generate it.

I've tried `for_each`, `for _, repo in local.services` and the `dynamic` block, but none of those seem to be valid.

The integrations variable in the api gateway module is defined with the type `map(any)`

Is this possible?

I've tried generating a local variable:

```
  integrations = [for _, repo in local.services: {
    "ANY /${repo}/{proxy+}" = {
      lambda_arn             = module.api_lambdas[repo].lambda_function_arn
      payload_format_version = "1.0"
      timeout_milliseconds   = 12000
    }
  }]
```

but that is of the wrong type.

I've tried a dynamic block:

```
  dynamic "integrations" {
    for_each = local.repositories
    content = {
      "ANY /${each.value}/{proxy+}" = {
        lambda_arn             = module.api_lambdas[each.value].lambda_function_arn
        payload_format_version = "1.0"
        timeout_milliseconds   = 12000
      }
    }
  }
```

but dynamic doesn't appear valid for a module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on some local testing (without having the module outputs of course), this should work:

```
module "api_gateway" {
  source = "../modules/apigateway"

  name          = "${var.name}-${var.env}-api-gateway"
  ...
 
  integrations = {
    for repo in local.services : "ANY /${repo}/{proxy+}" => {
      lambda_arn             = module.api_lambdas["${repo}"].lambda_function_arn
      payload_format_version = "1.0"
      timeout_milliseconds   = 12000
    }
  }  
}
```